# Assign value to a javascript prototype function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, variable-assignment, assign

I have written a javascript prototype function, in which i need to get value by passing variable like below

```
myarr.value(1,2)="Content";

myarr.prototype.value = function (rows,columns){
        console.log(rows,columns);
}
```

In the above function I'm getting rows and columns as 1 & 2, but getting error msg "invalid assignment left-hand side" for the content.

Help me to get the content in this way? and mention what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, yes, you cannot assign to a function call. It's unclear what you expect the result to be…

Comment: ``undefined = "Content"``. That's what your code does (assuming the first line is invoked on an object instance). There is no way this could work.

Comment: What is `myarr` ? A constructor ?

Comment: what `myarr.value(1,2)="Content";` you think should do?

Comment: I 'm trying to assign array value of [1,2] as "Content", i'm unclear of getting the variable.

Comment: It's a constructor

Comment: Is this a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: In the above question i didn't mention the code of assigning value to the array. I just want to get the content in this method. that's all i'm trying to do.

Comment: get what content ?

Comment: `myarr ` is a constructor , you need use `new` operator to generate an instance who's `__proto__` refers to the constructor's `prototype` .

Comment: myArr.value(1,2) = "Some Content"

Answer (score 0):

What is myarr ? Is it a kind of matrix ? How did you create it ?

From what I understand, you have a matrix and you want to set values using the coordinates... If you want to use the prototype like that it will not work... You have to create a Matrix object and add the value method to its prototype. Something like that

```js
var Matrix = function(/*Some initializers*/){
  // Initialize the matrix
}

Matrix.prototype.setValue = function(x, y, value){
  // return something
}

// Then you use it like that
var mymatrix = new Matrix();

myMatrix.setValue(2, 12, 'someValue');
```

But what it is important is that you have to define how you build your matrix and how you access the elements... Hope it helps

Comment: This is what i'm doing, but dont want to get content in this way like passing parameters, i need to get the content like "myMatrix.setValue(2,12) = "SomeValue"

Comment: You "need to" ? What are you trying to achieve ? What's the problem doing it like that ? You will not be able to do it like that except if you do something like this : myMatrix[2][12] = 'someValue'... But it means you dont use the prototype at all